# Test for space input from text box

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text box. I have this JS which will not allow user to enter special characters or spaces.

```
var reg = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/; 
if(reg.test(DivisionName) == false) {
   alert('Please enter Circle Name without special characters.');
   return false;
}
else{
   window.location.href="addCircles.jsp?DivisionName="+DivisionName+"&cancel=";
}
```

Now, I want to allow user to enter special characters but not only spaces. For example,

```
{"Stack OverFlow","$$ any"}
```

is allowed.

```
 {"   "}
```

is not allowed.When I remove the condition, it is allowing spaces. How can I do that?

Comment: Just need to change the regular expression. Check here for more info http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Just view this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Just a suggestion from an end-user perspective, wouldn't it be better to prevent space from being entered (like this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/AGAtz/)) rather than allowing the user to enter it and then display an error?

Comment: User is allowed to give space in between characters. He cannot give only space. For Example, the value in the text box can be "Stack Overflow" but not "  "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf) method on the input string:

```
function CheckForWhiteSpace(DivisionName) {
  return DivisionName.indexOf(' ') >= 0;
}
```

Or you can use the test method, on a simple RegularExpression:

```
function RegWhiteSpace(s) {
  return /\s/g.test(s);
}
```

This will also check for other white space characters like Tab.

**you should edit your question as it does not give correct info about your requirement.**

It's all about writing robust and maintainable code. If a user input contains space only

However, it might not be appropriate in all scenarios!

```
$.trim($(DivisionName)) === ""
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bladebreaker/xGuWA/)

Comment: can you give a demo in a fiddle??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bladebreaker/xGuWA/2/ here is your updated code. If it works for you please accept this as answer.

Comment: when i give 4 empty spaces, the value it showed is 'true'. It should be false.

Comment: well code is working correctly. if you want to get false returned if there is whitespace present then i have modified it. http://jsfiddle.net/bladebreaker/xGuWA/3/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can give us an example of what inputs would be valid, and which ones would be invalid? 
That way we could help you with the regex.

For example:

```
var tests = [
'',    // bad
' ',    // bad
' foo', // bad
'foo ', // bad
'foo', // good
'foo bar' // good
]
var regex = /^[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*]+(\s[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*]+)*$/
for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++){
    console.log('"' + tests[i] + '"=' + regex.test(tests[i]))
}
```

Gives:

```
""=false
" "=false
" foo"=false
"foo "=false
"foo"=true
"foo bar"=true
```

Example here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkQf2/)

Answer (score 0):

[Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/USJws/)

**HTML**

```
<input>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("input").on("keydown", function (e) {
    return e.which !== 32;
});
```

This will allow all alphabets,letters,special characters except whitespace..

Comment: I want to allow space in between characters. "Stack Overflow" is allowed. "   " is not allowed.

Comment: I dont think so you can do that..if keypress is disabled,its bool value is false for that process.Meanwhile you cant change.Else you need to pass it to a seperate function and do it..Cant achieve on keyup or keydown.